# Wifi with GameKit

Tags: ipad, ipod, gamekit

I asked questions a month ago about a project where an instructor has an iPad and a bunch (oh, 15 we'll say) of students have iPod Touches. The students need to send answers to the instructor and the instructor needs to issue new questions to the students. From what I've been researching, bluetooth connection using GameKit only allows up to four devices. Since I need more than that, I know I need to deal with wifi connection with GameKit. I have tried to find tutorials, example code, etc. for this, but I just keep finding people saying "you'll have to implement it yourself." My question is, how do I go about implementing wifi with GameKit? Brian mentioned a hosted match that can have up to 16 devices, does anyone know of a tutorial or example on hosted matches? Any links would be very much appreciated, I just really need a place to start!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bonjour Framework instead of gamekit..
it allows you to create server and connect as many clients to it .
publishing the service etc all can be done..
For reference follow the following Book :-

Beginning.iPhone.Games.Development by PJ Cabrera.